# Insert line breaks in hidden fields value - Java

Tags: java, jsp

How would I go about inserting line breaks in the value of hidden fields?

For ex. this is how my hidden field looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dahidden" value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %> <%=da.getEmail() %> <%=da.getPhone() %> <%=da.getExt() %>">
```

I tried the following:

```
value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %> \n <%=da.getEmail() %> ..." 

value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %> '\n' <%=da.getEmail() %>..." 

value="<%=da.getFname() %> <%=da.getLname() %> <br> <%=da.getEmail() %>..."
```

But all of them don't actually resolve to the newline character, and get displayed as \n, '\n', and 
 respectively.

Thanks,
Pritish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert them plain.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=da.getFname() %>
<%=da.getLname() %>
<%=da.getEmail() %>">
```

---

That said, have you considered taglibs/EL? *Scriptlets* are [discrouaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since a decade. If you've learnt them from some book/tutorial, I think it's high time to replace it by a more decent/recent one to avoid future troubles.